# Index Finger Mittens for Biking

Tags: gloves, cold, mittens, fingers

I have a condition that affects circulation to my fingers and lately I've been wanting something warmer than gloves with liners for biking.  The solution seems to be something called "index finger mittens."  They're just mittens with a separate index finger for a trigger or brake lever.

I live far enough south that I've never seen or heard of these things.  Apparently they might also be called one of the following:
split-finger mittens
3 finger mittens/gloves
lobster mittens/gloves
trigger finger mittens

Since I live in a county with only two paved roads I have the usual problem of no in-person shopping options and reduced options online.  Amazon stopped honoring their "free returns" out here a little over a year ago.  I stopped shopping there rather than pay UPS for a pickup every time I have a problem with an item.

I didn't see good options on walmart or temu.  Aliexpress has a handful of options but I worry about quality with that site, and they're still more like snowboarding mittens than biking mittens.

(EDIT: after a 2nd look at the options on aliexpress it turns out these are the only ones that would fit me: https://www.aliexpress.us/item/2255800334665556.html size medium)

Any suggestions?

Comment: I find that full mittens work fine on flat bars, and moderately well with road bars. Have you tried them / is there something in your setup that needs the extra split?

Comment: I have a gravel bike with drop bars and normally ride holding the brake hoods with three fingers under and the index finger on the lever.  Good to know I can use full mittens on flat bars for the future tho.

Comment: I assume there are no online shopping options with free returns?

Comment: Walmart.com sort of does free returns.  They normally don't want the items sent back and the times they said Fedex would pick up I got a refund but the item sat on the porch for weeks until I brought it back in.  Weird but whatever.  I'll probably buy a vehicle in the next 3-4 years and Walmart's only 33 miles away.  That highway has literally less than zero shoulder in some places (the road is crumbling) so there's no way I can bike there with my trailer unfortunately.

Answer (score 4):

We avoid product recommendations here, but I would encourage you to investigate buying from an online bike store. There are some big, well-known ones in the USA (Competitive Cyclist), UK (Merlin Cycles), and Germany (Bike 24, Rose Bikes) that ship internationally. Just looking through Rose Bikes' website, I see four options for lobster gloves. I'd feel a lot better about buying from them than AliExpress.

Comment: Thanks for those names!  I normally don't trust aliexpress with anything over $10 but in this instance we're talking about a 3-5x price difference between them and the cycling retailers so I might take a gamble and see if they're good enough for occasional use.

Comment: I don't mind AE for non-critical parts.  Asian gloves are often sized small, and their idea of "waterproof" isn't.  Also the Asian concept of "cold" doesn't equate to mine.   But for $5 when the local item is $50, I can buy 5, use the best one and still pay only half local retail cost.    For critical things like brakes?  No way.